# Python code to jumback at the beginning of the program/code?

Tags: python, python-3.7, goto

Is there any code in Python i can use to jump back in the beginning of the code without using functions?
E.g:

```
Beginning:

num_greet = 2

While num_greetings <= 2:

      print("Hi my name is Joe")
else:
     print("Type a number that is less than 2")

     goto Beginning
```

Comment: One of the best things about python is that it doesn't have `goto`, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: A better-placed while loop that starts at the first line?

Comment: The code you've posted makes no sense. Even if all the typos and syntax errors were corrected, the else-block would never be entered because `num_greetings` never changes.

Comment: https://github.com/JoeDimumbi/Password-Generator/blob/master/Password_Gen.py
I'm trying to use the "goto" on the password generator above